# Creating a coordinate out of two ints Java

Tags: java

just a quick question.

If i'm trying to instantiate an object which takes 3 ints, and 2 coordinates, why does eclipse complain when I do the following...

```
private int x,y;
private int x1, y1;

public Objects(int xo, int yo, int zo, (int x1, int y1), (int x2, y2)){
     this.(x,y) = (x1, y1);
     this.(x1,y1) = (x2, y2);

}
```

Comment: what is `this.(x,y) = (x1, y1);`

Comment: Because that's not valid Java syntax?

Comment: what makes you think that `this.(x,y) = (x1, y1);` *should* work?

Comment: Where the heck did you see such syntax?

Comment: But what if my task at hand is to create Instantiate a object that holds 3 integers and 2 coordinates. Would I need a function that makes a coordinate inside the class?

Comment: Then you'd pass an object that represented a coordinate and held those values. [`Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) comes to mind

Comment: Your 2 coords can be represented by another class which you pass in.

Comment: Thank you guys, I understand it now. I'm waiting on accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not legal Java syntax. You can't have parentheses in the method signature's arguments.

Your alternative is to define a class, `Coordinate`, and pass instances of this class to the method.

Comment: Thank you @Kon, and I don't know why you got downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

`private int x, y;` in fact is shorthand for creating two separate variables, equivalent to

```
private int x;
private int y;
```

So you cannot use `(x,y)` to refer to a pair of variables. Either make an array, or better yet, a `Coordinate` class like:

```
public class Coordinate {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    // methods.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you want something like that.

One class for holding coordinates:

```
public class Coords {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

And another class:

```
public class WantedClass {
    int firstInteger;
    int secondInteger;
    int thirdInteger;
    Coords firstCoordinates;
    Coords secondCoordinates;
}
```

Constructors? Go figure them out yourself or I'll put them later if you still need them [ how SO of me ].